# SQL server week ending Thursday range

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to show the `DateTimeRaised` field as a week ending Thursday. The `FkIssueGroupID` isn't unique but each row should have the same date. The `MAX` is being used to bring back a single row.

```
Select distinct w.fkIssueGroupID
,[FormDateTimeRaised] =MAX ([DateTimeRaised])
,[WEnd Raised - Thur]= max (CONVERT (date, DATEADD(dd, 5 - (DATEPART(dw, [DateTimeRaised])), [DateTimeRaised]) ))
```

Whilst the week ending value for Thursday is correct the week days contained within it don't line up i.e.:

Week ending Thursday will have a date of the 21/05/20 (Thursday) but the date values covered by the data are 18/05 to 24/05 (Mon-Sun). I want the date range covered to be  15/05 to 21/05 (Fri-Thur). How do i get the date range to shift from Mon-Sun to Fri-Thur?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the first day of the week to Friday like this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 5;
```

Comment: Is there anyway to apply that to a particular field in the query as  there are other fields that need to be reported as week ending Sunday, so i don't want to set it a query level.

Comment: I don't think that's possible,no.  Try creating your own calendar table.  You can add a column for DayOfTheWeek and another for AlternativeDayOfTheWeek for example.